# Is there a way to prevent a user to uninstall an app?

Tags: android, google-play, device-admin

I'm making an android **anti-thief app**. I want to prevent a thief to uninstall the anti-thief app.

The app is a device administrator. So I used `DeviceAdminReceiver.onDisabled`
 to start a *“always on top”* password prompt `Activity` (the password is setup by the user during the app configuration). This works fine.

But, Google Play rejected the app. Email extract:

> Read through the Device and Network Abuse policy and make the
>   appropriate changes to your app. You’ll need to remove any
>   functionality that prevents a user from removing or uninstalling the
>   app from their device.

**My Question:**

What other ways can I use to prevent unauthorized user to:

- uninstall my device administrator app ?
- disable the device administrator permission ?

Thanks

EDIT: reformulate the question to clarify that the question is not about google play policy, but about alternative implementation.

Comment: That's odd considering the DevicePolicyManager actually allows admin apps to prevent uninstallation of specific apps.  They may only allow this for internal apps. http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setUninstallBlocked(android.content.ComponentName, java.lang.String, boolean)

Comment: @DeeV: AFAIK, that is for device owner apps, not mere device administrator apps.

Comment: "complying with Google play policy" -- questions about Play Store policies are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: @CommonsWare That is possibly true in which case you wouldn't be able to do this with apps distributed through Google Play I guess.

Comment: You can't publish device locking apps on Google Play. Such apps are by definition the same as ransomware and Google simply does not want that in their store.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Play policy

Comment: SIMPLY YOU CAN'T. unless if your app is system app yet they can uninstall it if they have root permission. so the answer is NO